# download file yii error 403

Tags: file, yii, download

I'm trying to make a link to download file from yii folder, the link can appear but when I clicked it show an error `Error 403 You are not authorized to perform this action.`

these are my code :

```
public function actionView2($id)
{
    $this->render('view2',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

_view.php

```
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('image')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->image), array('view2', 'id'=>$data->image), array('target'=>'_blank'));

?>
<br />
```

view2.php

```
<h1>View2  #<?php echo $model->image; ?></h1>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'image',
    ),
)); ?>
```

I thought it caused of authorization or something like that, but I'm not change anything in accessRules or UserIdentity.php

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

UserIdentity.php

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $users=array(
        // username => password
        'demo'=>'demo',
        'admin'=>'admin',
    );
    if(!isset($users[$this->username]))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    elseif($users[$this->username]!==$this->password)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

I will try this method as hard as I can, but if this can't be solved, is there another best way to do a "download link"?

Comment: Is the folder protected within the Yii system?

Comment: no, it is not. I already change the permission to full (rwx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action `view2` is not listed as allowed action in your `accessRules`, so it will hit the `deny` rule at the bottom.